# How can i Intro Screen using Dependency in android

Tags: android

I have an android application I want to add intro screen to my application is der any dependency to achieve this.

Comment: What you mean by 'dependency' ? I think you can achieve same behaviour by customising Activity

Comment: Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you mean a splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

i got answer

Create an Intro Slider Screen in Your Android App That Attract New Audience. Shares. ... Creating a welcome slider screen in your native Android app is one of the great ways to present the most important and major features of your app. And this is where, you can convince your new comers to become permanent users.

http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/10/android-appintro-slider-example.html